# Legato-AF platform [ Can’t find dependent .api file: ‘le_mdc.api’ ]

Tags: c++, embedded, wireless, legato

In Legato-af (legato) environment:

```
*Linux Ubuntu 
*Sierra Wireless WP76xx and WP77xx target 
*Legato shell (lsh:wp76stable)
```

I'm getting the following response:

(lsh:wp76stable) error: Can't find dependent .api file: 'le_mdc.api'

The same error is in wp77stable profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Can't find dependent .api file: 'le_mdc.api'" typically occurs when the Legato build system is unable to find a required API file. This can be caused by a number of issues, such as:

1. The API file is not present in the expected location.

   Make sure that the API file is located in the correct directory and is spelled correctly.
2. The API file is not included in the build.

   Make sure that the API file is included in the build by adding it to the appropriate component.cdef or app.cdef file.
3. There is a problem with the build system configuration.

   Make sure that the build system is properly configured and that all required dependencies are specified.
4. API file

   ```
   $LEGATO_ROOT/interfaces/le_data.api
   ```

   is referencing

   ```
   $LEGATO_ROOT/interfaces/modemServices/le_mdc.api
   ```

   what is the source of the problem.

   **What worked for me was a simple copy of le_mdc.api
   into the same folder with le_data.api**